# sqlalchemy order table by foreign key

Tags: sql

I have a table which holds 2 foreign keys to another table:

```
Table A{
primary_key
foreign_key_1_to_table_B
foreign_key_2_to_table_B
}

Table B{
primary_key
a_character_column
}
```

Now I want to sort the rows of table A according to a_character_column but as this is referenced by foreign_key_1_to_table_B.

All the queries are implemented in sqlalchemy, but since this is a generic problem I'd rather use pseudo sql.

Any idea how to form the ORDER BY clause of the sql query?

I should add that I need a join between A and B for both foreign_key_1_to_table_B and foreign_key_2_to_table_B. The problem arises when I try to specify whether the ordering should be done with respect to the foreign_key_1_to_table_b or foreign_key_2_to_table_B.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL it'd be

```
select A.* 
from A 
inner join B on (A.foreign_key_1_to_table_B = B.primary_key
order by B.a_character_column
```

Comment: I have rephrased a bit my question, since I realised that it was not very clear. You answer would indeed cover the case where I perform a single join to table B, but it does not cover the case where I perform 2 joins to B.